# PP Chain and CNO cycle relationship

Tags: astrophysics, nuclear-physics, temperature, fusion, stellar-physics

At what temperature would the energy generation rates of the PP-Chain and CNO cycles be roughly equivalent? The dependences are so vastly different that I am wondering how and by what equations they could be related.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question properly, but the graph here at least gives an idea of what's going on: http://csep10.phys.utk.edu/astr162/lect/energy/cno-pp.html

Answer (score 4):

The amount of energy liberated per gram of material per second in the fusion reactions depends on the density, the [mass fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_fraction_(chemistry)) (hydrogen, $X$, helium, $Y$, and all others $Z$) and temperature:
$$
\epsilon = \epsilon(\rho,X, Y, Z, T)
$$
Typically we express the energy generation rate as a power law, 
$$
\epsilon\propto\rho^\alpha T^\delta.
$$
though the "true" forms are not too far off (usually containing an exponential term).

For the [pp-chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction), the energy generation rate takes the form,
$$
\epsilon_{pp}\sim1.05\times10^{-5}\rho X^2T_6^4 \,\rm erg/g/s\tag{1}
$$
where $X$ is the mass fraction of hydrogen and $T_6=T/10^6\,\rm K$. For the [CNO cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle), the energy generation rate is
$$
\epsilon_{CNO}\sim8.24\times10^{-24}\rho XX_{CNO} T_6^{19.9}\,\rm erg/g/s\tag{2}
$$
where $X_{CNO}$ is the mass fraction of carbon, nitrogen & oxygen. If we assume that $\rho X^2\approx \rho XX_{CNO}$, then we can iteratively compute the equilibrium temperature to be around 
$$
T_{eq}\sim16,500,000\,\rm K
$$
In the figure below, which plots the energy generation rates as a function of temperature (in $T_6$ units), the matched temperature *looks* to be around $T_6\sim17$, which is slightly above the equilibrium temperature I found above.

[image]
([source](http://csep10.phys.utk.edu/astr162/lect/energy/cno-pp.html))

Note that the figure uses $\epsilon_{CNO}\propto T^{17}$ while (2) contains $\epsilon_{CNO}\propto T^{19.9}$. This is because the book I used, [Carroll & Ostlie](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805304029) (Amazon link), gives the latter form that I've used and I trust that book.

Comment: Nice. It would be even better if there was also a figure showing the variation for fixed temperature and varying $X_{CNO}/X$ as that is more closely coupled to the evolution of loss mass stars.